# What is this texture called and how can I match it?

Tags: drywall, paint, texture

I repaired a 2' x 4' section of our ceiling, and I'd like to match the surrounding texture.

Is this a sprayed texture like orange peel, or just some kind of roller stipple?

[image]

Assuming it was orange peel, I tried matching it with a Homax spray gun.  I did get a decent orange peel, but it's a lot more 'blotchy' than the one I'm trying to match, which has very small raised bumps.

I've tried various combinations of mud, pressure, etc.  My last attempt was joint compound thinned 4:1 with water, 70 PSI, and a 4mm tip.  I'm using a Porter Cable C2002 (6 Gal 150 PSI) compressor.

Note that the gun needs 7CFM @ 25PSI, which is probably more than the compressor can do - the C2002 is rated 3.5 SCFM @ 40PSI.  But I'm not sure if that's the problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Nice question: big props for including the tape measure in the image. I'm no expert, but my guess is "matching textures is hard" is about the best answer you'll get.

Comment: Looks like roller marks to me... if it sprayed on, it will most likely be airless. If you're worried about matching something as basic as that, just redo the whole ceiling.

Answer (score 1):

For such a small area, you might consider the ceiling texture in a spray can with an adjustable tip. Get whichever one says 'orange peel'. (Note that there are water based ones that dry relatively slowly and other ones that dry more quickly.) You'll be able to get a credible match. An exact match is tough, so don't beat yourself up too much over it.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your help.  I did try the canned products, but they produced an orange peel which was too 'flat' without the raised peaks shown.

I ended up matching the texture perfectly with the Homax nozzle set to spray a minimum amount of mix, along with a very thick mix (mud:water of 2:1) at 75 PSI.